# Input from user to print out a certain instance variable in python

Tags: python, list, class, input, try-except

I have created a class with programs:

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self,channel,start, end, name, viewers, percentage):
        self.channel = channel
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.name = name
        self.viewers = viewers
```

```
Channel 1, start:16.00 end:17.45 viewers: 100 name: Matinee:The kiss on the cross 
Channel 1, start:17.45 end:17.50 viewers: 45 name: The stock market today
Channel 2, start:16.45 end:17.50 viewers: 30 name: News
Channel 4, start:17.25 end:17.50 viewers: 10 name: Home building 
Channel 5, start:15.45 end:16.50 viewers: 28 name: Reality
```

I also have created a nested list with the programs:

```
[[1,16:00, 17,45, 100, 'Matinee: The kiss on the cross'],[1,17:45, 17,50, 45,'The stock market today'],[2,16:45, 17,50, 30,'News'], [4,17:25, 17,50, 10,'Home building'],[5,15:45, 16,50, 28,'Reality']
```

Now we want the user to be able to write the name of a program:

> News

The result should be:

> News 19.45-17.50 has 30 viewers

I thought about how you could incorporate a method to avoid the program from crashing if the input is invalid/ not an instance variable

I have tried this:

```
Check_input():
 print('Enter the name of the desired program:')
    
    while True:                               #Continue asking for valid input.
        try:
            name = input('>')
            if name == #is an instance?
                return name 
            else:
                print('Enter a program that is included in the schedule:')   #input out of range

        except ValueError:
            print('Write a word!')        #Word or letter as input
            print('Try again')
```

I wonder if I should separate all the program-names from the nested list and check if the user enters a name in the list as input? (Maybe by creating a for-loop to iterate over?)

I also have a question regarding how to print out the selected program when the user enters the correct name? I understand how to rearrange them into the correct order to create the sentence. However, I don't know how to access the correct program in the "memory"

Do you have any suggestions how to combat the problem?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if I should separate all the program-names from the nested list and check if the user enters a name in the list as input? (Maybe by creating a for-loop to iterate over?)

Well if all your programs have a unique name then the easiest approach would probably be to store them in a dictionary instead of a nested list like:

```
programs = {
    "News": Program("2", "16:45", "17:50", "News", "30", "60"),
    "Reality": <Initialize Program class object for this program>,
    ...
}
```

Then you could just use the `get` dictionary method (it allows you to return a specific value if the key does not exist) to see if the asked program exists:

```
name = input('>')     
program = programs.get(name, None)
if program:
    print(program)
else:
    # raise an exception or handle however you prefer
```

And if your programs don't have a unique name then you will have to iterate over the list. In which case I would probably return a list of all existing objects that have that `name`. A `for` loop would work just fine, but I would switch the nested list with a list of Program objects since you already have the class.

> I also have a question regarding how to print out the selected program when the user enters the correct name? I understand how to rearrange them into the correct order to create the sentence. However, I don't know how to access the correct program in the "memory" Do you have any suggestions how to combat the problem.

I would say that the most elegant solution is to override the `__str__` method of your Program class so that you can just call `print(program)` and write out the right output. For example:

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self,channel,start, end, name, viewers, percentage):
        self.channel = channel
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.name = name
        self.viewers = viewers 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.start + "-" + self.end + " has " + self.viewers + " viewers"
```

should print out

> News 19.45-17.50 has 30 viewers

when you call it like:

```
program = programs.get(name, None)
if program:
    print(program)
```